# Regular Expression Time Format?

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression which accept time in a specific format like the following,
"10:00".

I want to change the regular expression to etiher accpet this format or accept only a single one dash only ("-").

Here is the expression:

```
/^((\d)|(0\d)|(1\d)|(2[0-3]))\:((\d)|([0-5]\d))$/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key points to solving this:

- Square brackets (`[` and `]`) are used to enclose character classes.
- The pipe `|` means `or`.
- `[\:|-]` means chech for either a literal `:` or a hyphen `-`.

The resulting pattern is:

```
^((\d)|(0\d)|(1\d)|(2[0-3]))[\:|-]((\d)|([0-5]\d))$
```

Comment: Looks like i misunderstood, i thought you meant 10:00 or 10-00. Apologies!

Comment: Either you or me misunderstood the question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use an alternative:

```
^<your regex>$|^-$
```

This will match either a time in your format or a single hyphen-minus.

Answer (score 0):

Does this regex need to have so many brackets?

```
/^(([01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d|-)$/
```